# Getting "InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found." while running ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I wonder if some one could suggest a solution, this drives me insane. I looked for the solution for this known issue for hours, none that is suggested works for me.

I have a simple ASP.NET CORE application in VS 2022, built a simple HomeController, the breakpoint hits that controller, but it can never find the view

I get this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
> following locations were searched: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

I know that I have to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation package but when I try to do it from the Nugit I get this error

> Error NU1202  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
> 7.0.5 is not compatible with net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 7.0.5
> supports: net7.0

I keep adding new methods to my Program.cs file, but nothing works, here is my Program.cs file so far

```
using SamepleApi;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();//AddControllersAsServices();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(typeof(HomeController).Assembly);
//builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
//{
//    endpoints.MapControllers();

//    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
//        name: "default",
//        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
//});

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Here is how my solution explorer looks

[image]

Just in case I also add the controller code

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SampleReference;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System;
namespace SamepleApi
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //QB_USERNAME = RMTW
            //QB_PASSWORD = Yellow3!!
            var svc = new QBWebConnectorSvcSoapClient(QBWebConnectorSvcSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.QBWebConnectorSvcSoap);
            var cv = svc.clientVersionAsync("");
            var sv = svc.serverVersionAsync("1.0");
            svc.authenticateAsync("RMTW", "Yellow3!!");
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if anyone could suggest a solution, thank you in advance!

Comment: The error seems self explanatory. You are returning a view, but you haven't added a file to your project for the view. Put an index.cshtml file in a Home folder within the Views folder that already exists. The error message is even kind enough to tell you the paths it looked for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding the nuget package, you should select the version 6.0. Then the installation will complete and you can proceed as usual

[image]

This is the sample for Newtownsoft.json, you can do the same for MVC and change the version from 7.0 to any of Version started from 6.0.

Beside, you can also opt to upgrade your project to 7.0

Answer (score 4):

Looks like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` needs to be installed. After that it should be enabled `builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`
Works for **net7.0**

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSOnRqHMHs